# How to get the filename of email attachments in imap and pop3 without downloading?

Tags: ruby, email, imap, email-attachments, pop3

I have a use case where I want to get the filenames of all the attachments of a particular email without having to download the attachments. Is is possible using IMAP and POP3 ?

I am using ruby's Net::IMAP and NET::POP3 classes.

Comment: It is not possible in POP3. It does not have protocol features to download parts of a message.

Answer (score 1):

This should print info about the attachment ( not tested ) but you can check it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/muZIOmSsKHw)

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('domain.name.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'mailbox', 'password')
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(["SINCE", "8-Aug-2002"]).each do |message_id|
attach = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY")[0].attr["BODY"]
  puts "#{attach.parts[1].media_type}"
  puts "#{attach.parts[1].param['NAME']}"
  puts "#{attach.parts[1].subtype}"
  puts "#{(attach.parts[1].size)/1024} kb"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using IMAP `.filename`

```
require 'net/imap'
require 'mail'

imap = Net::IMAP.new('HOST', 993, true)
imap.login('username@mail.com', 'PASSWORD')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["SINCE", "30-Nov-2020"]).each do |message_id|
  body = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY[]")[0].attr["BODY[]"]
  mail = Mail.new(body)
  mail.attachments.each do |a|
    p a.filename
end
```